# Emacs tag/navigation on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, emacs, navigation, tags

Basically the objective is to enable emacs jumping to definitions, like moving to function definitions in c++ for example, on Windows 7.

Tried to follow 
http://adoxa.altervista.org/global/
from
https://www.gnu.org/software/global/global.html

First it is not clear fro me regarding how to use http://adoxa.altervista.org/global/. What I did was to unzip 'GLOBAL 6.5.6 Win32' and ammended PATH variable to look to the binaries therein. Then I added this to ~/.emacs

```
(setq load-path (cons "D:/path/glo656wb/share/gtags/gtags.el" load-path))
;;(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/path/glo656wb/share/gtags/gtags.el")

(autoload 'gtags-mode "gtags" "" t)

;; C-mode
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 
   '(lambda () 
      (gtags-mode t)
))
```

But am getting this error message
"Can not open load file, no such file or directory..."

Any idea? What is the proper way to setup this on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `"D:/path/glo656wb/share/gtags/gtags.el"` a *directory*? The doc of `load-path` says that its elements need to be directories.  `C-h v load-path`:

> `load-path` is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is shown below.
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> List of directories to search for files to load.
>
> Each element is a string (directory file name) or nil (meaning
>   `default-directory`).
>
> This list is consulted by the `require` function.
>
> Initialized during startup as described in Info node [`(elisp)Library Search`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Search.html).
>   Use `directory-file-name` when adding items to this path.  However, Lisp
>   programs that process this list should tolerate directories both with
>   and without trailing slashes.

Comment: Do we need to install gtags on windows? If yes, then how since the guide is for linux?